# Find and communicate cross subnet

Tags: android, c++, linux, sockets, tcp

In the same Local area network，how to  find each other and communicate cross subnet?

eg.clientA(10.66.128.75) and clientB(10.66.127.70) both join same Multicast Addresses(224.0.1.1) .How could they find each other and communicate cross subnet?

Comment: In practice this kind of setup is harder to support (troubleshooting is tricky), that is why most developers opt for a central server design instead (also it makes authorization and authentication easier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is UPnP. You may want to take a look at [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) - a Java UPnP stack compatible with Android